# Javascript module programming

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm study module programming.
take a look at below code:

```
var goodsspec = function(){

    function setSpec(){
        var
        _price,
        _storage,
        defaultstats = true,
        _val = '',
        _resp = {
                    storage:".goods_stock",
                    price:".price"
                }

        $(".sys_item_spec .sys_item_specpara").each(function(){
            var i = $(this);
            var v = i.attr("data-attrval");
            if(!v){
                      defaultstats = false;
            }else{
                      val += _val!=""?"":"";
                      _val += v;
                 }
        });

        if(!!defaultstats){  

            _storage = sys_item['sys_attrprice'][_val]['goods_storage'];
            _price = sys_item['sys_attrprice'][_val]['price'];
        }else{
                _storage = sys_item['goods_storage'];
                _price = sys_item['price'];
             }

        $(_resp.storage).text( _storage);
        $(_resp.price).text( _price);
        if ( _storage == 0){
                // Waring

            }

        }
        return {
            set:function(){
               return setSpec();
            }
        };
    }();

    console.log(goodsspec.price);
```

I want to get _price and storage property value _value when I selected item.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
   var Item = new Object();

   function setSpec(){
     // setting code
     Item.price = _price;
     Item.storage = _storage
   }
```

then you could use

```
console.log("Prices is "+Item.price+" for "+Item.storage+".");
```